# Java 8 Streams filtering out empty String[] from List<String[]>?

Tags: java, java-8, stream, java-stream

Assuming we have 2 test String[], something like:

```
String[] test = {"","","","",""};
String[] test2 = {"Test","Name", "5.00", "NY", "Single"};
```

And then we append them to a list like this:

```
List<String[]> testList = new ArrayList<>();
testList.add(test);
testList.add(test2);
```

The goal of what I am trying to do is to find the sum of the dollars paid, in index 2 of each String[] using Java 8 streams. But I can't seem to filter out the String[] containing empty values in each indice. Here is my attempt:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] test = {"","","","",""};
        String[] test2 = {"Test","Name", "5.00", "NY", "Single"};
        List<String[]> testList = new ArrayList<>();
        testList.add(test);
        testList.add(test2);
        System.out.println(testList);
        testList.stream().map(Arrays::asList).filter(i -> !i.isEmpty())
                                             .mapToDouble(columnsPerRow -> 
                                                Double.parseDouble(columnsPerRow.get(2)))
                                             .sum();
        System.out.println(testList);
    }
```

My attempt to filter it was using **filter(i -> !i.isEmpty())**

The error it throws is still:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at Main.lambda$main$0(Main.java:23)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$6$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:244)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.DoublePipeline.collect(DoublePipeline.java:500)
    at java.util.stream.DoublePipeline.sum(DoublePipeline.java:411)
    at Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're filtering on the wrong entity:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] test = {"","","","",""};
    String[] test2 = {"Test","Name", "5.00", "NY", "Single"};
    String[] test3 = {"Test","Name", "13.00", "NY", "Single"};
    List<String[]> testList = new ArrayList<>();
    testList.add(test);
    testList.add(test2);
    testList.add(test3);
    double sum = testList.stream()
                    .map(Arrays::asList)
                    .filter(i -> i.size() > 2 && !i.get(2).isEmpty())
                    .mapToDouble(columnsPerRow -> Double.parseDouble(columnsPerRow.get(2)))
                    .sum();
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Produces `18.0` as expected.

The filter stage removes arrays that are shorter than 2 elements or where the 2nd element is empty.

Comment: May I ask what the .filter(i -> i.size() > 1) part does?

Comment: Prevents you from attempting to invoke `get(2)` when the input array had fewer than 2 elements, which would throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.  If you can provably _guarantee_ that the input arrays all have more than 2 elements you can omit it.

Comment: Also I had a typo, I meant `i.size() > 2`.  Fixed.

Comment: Perfect thank you, i've actually used .filter(i -> !i.get().isEmpty)) before, but for some reason i was trying to take out the entire String[] by filtering out every indice in it instead of just the important one, shame on me haha thank you though

Comment: Doing `.get` 2 times, isn't the optimal way

Comment: @azro indeed, but even the `map(Arrays::asList)` is entirely unnecessary. The task can be done as simple as `testList.stream().map(a -> a.length > 2? a[2]: "") .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()) .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble) .sum()`

Answer (score 2):

In `i -> !i.isEmpty()`, `i` is the `ArrayList`, and it contains `("","","","","")` si it isn't empty, you may check for the value at index 2, you can do it that way

```
double r = testList.stream().map(Arrays::asList)
                   .filter(i -> !i.isEmpty())              // ensure list not empty
                   .map(i -> i.get(2))                     // keep only 3rd element
                   .filter(i -> !i.isEmpty())              // ensure string isn't empty
                   .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)       // map to double
                   .sum();
```

The first `.filter(i -> !i.isEmpty())` could be replaced by `.filter(i -> i.size() >= 3)`

Answer (score 1):

Taking your word for it, *filter out the String[] containing empty values in each indice.*

```
    String[] test = {"","","","",""};
    String[] test2 = {"Test","Name", "5.00", "NY", "Single"};

    double total = Stream.of(test, test2)
            .filter(arr -> !Arrays.stream(arr).allMatch(String::isEmpty))
            .mapToDouble(arr -> Double.parseDouble(arr[2]))
            .sum();
    
    System.out.println(total);
```

Output is:

> 5.0

My code only filters out string arrays where *all* the values are empty strings. So it will break with an exception if the dollar value is `""` and the array contains other non-empty strings. Which is what you should want of an array without dollar value is required to hold only empty strings. For the sake of validation. You will probably want to catch the `NumerFormatException` and report a validation error. Or maybe validate the stream before doing your computation.

Comment: With the answers above, couldn't I tack on your .filter(arr -> !Arrays.stream(arr).allMatch(String::isEmpty)) as well to cover both scenarios?

Comment: I am not sure what two scenarios you mean or what you would win by combining two answers, but yes, you certainly can do that.